# Azure Resource tag change history/Restore deleted tags

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-vm

We have an azure environment with multiple vms with a number of tags. A process ran overnight that replaced all the tags with another new tag(both key and value). I would like to recover the old tags. I am aware that the application change analysis feature will give me the details on GUI/portal.

I am looking to have this info ready to be exported(csv,txt etc), as we have 100s of VMs. Is there a powershell/CLI/any other method by which I can capture this data.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the [Resource Change History API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/public-preview-change-history-api/) that is in Public Preview.

With the last 14 days of change history, Azure Resource Graph enables you to:

- Find when changes were detected on an Azure Resource Manager property
- For each resource change, see property change details See a full
- comparison of the resource before and after the detected change

For the preview, two API actions are now available in the Azure Resource Graph API:

- **resourceChanges:** returns a list of change events for a resource and time interval
- **resourceChangeDetails:** returns the before and after resource content for a given resource and change event

Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/how-to/get-resource-changes) for the detailed description and examples.